# Connection pooling in System.DirectoryServices.Protocols (S.DS.P)

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, directoryservices

I'm struggling with `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols` (S.DS.P) in an ASP.NET Helpdesk application to manage users and security groups.

I want to implement connection pooling for my LDAP connections and I can´t really find any good articles or information about successful patterns for solving the problem with too many TIME_WAIT TCP connections on my Active Directory Server.

How do you solve this issue in your ASP.NET applications?